# retorno de array_search() considerado condição falsa

Tags: php, array, session

Em meu código, na tela de login busco no BD o número de blogs que pertencem ao mesmo usuário e coloco o ID desses blogs em uma array, depois a atribuo a uma variável de sessão (quero que meu código permita ao usuário depois de logado acessar seus blogs apenas mudando a ID na url). Depois que o usuário está em seu blog e muda a url, utilizo a variável de sessão **$blogs** e comparo ela com a url alterada (**$url**).
    O código abaixo deveria verificar se a array (com 2 posições), referente a variável de sessão, contêm a url passada pelo usuário. O problema é que o PHP considera o índice 0 da array ( retorno da função array_search() ) como uma condição falsa, desse modo, considera que o usuário tem apenas 1 blog. Gostaria de saber como reescrever o código para evitar esse problema:

```
if( isset($_GET['idBlog']) ){
    $url = $_GET['idBlog'];
    $blogs = $_SESSION['idBlog'];
    if( is_array($blogs) ){
        $index = array_search($url, $blogs);
        if( !is_nan($index) ){
            $blogAtual = $blogs[$index];
        } else {
            $msg = "<script> alert('O blog que você quer acesar não é seu') </script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi direito, basta você mudar a verificaçao:

```
if( is_array($blogs) ){

    if( ($index = array_search($url, $blogs)) !== false ){
            $blogAtual = $blogs[$index];
        } else {
            $msg = "<script> alert('O blog que você quer acesar não é seu') </script>";
    }
}
```